# How to make rectagle (with triangle from right) border gradient?

Tags: css, svg

I have a problem with CSS3/SVG button. I don't know how to make linear gradient gradient border like that:

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NiUt.png)

Top button: button has transparent background

Bottom button: button on hover has gradient background (same as on border) with opacity 30%, if it is not possible to do such a gradient background when you hover it can change only the color of border

Comment: How far have you got? Add your code so far to the question.

Comment: Not much... I find example http://codepen.io/Afonin/pen/eJGqNX and I have no idea how create triangle from right on border...

Answer (score 1):

I have created one demo for you. Though you would have to change the colors it looks almost as you wanted it.

To create the gradient you can use [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) awesome online tool.

```css
.container{
  background:blue;
  padding:100px;
  float:left;
}
.outsider{
  padding:4px 0px 4px 4px;
  float:left;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#8887d3+0,cbebff+43,ffffff+100 */
background: rgb(136,135,211); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(136,135,211,1) 0%, rgba(203,235,255,1) 43%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(136,135,211,1) 0%,rgba(203,235,255,1) 43%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(136,135,211,1) 0%,rgba(203,235,255,1) 43%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8887d3', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
position:relative;
}
.outsider:after{
      content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 43px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 43px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid #FFFFFF;
    top: 0px;
}
.outsider:before{
        content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -26px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 39px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 39px solid transparent;
    border-left: 26px solid #0000FF;
    top: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.insider{
  padding:30px;
  float:left;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outsider">
    <div class="insider">
      Lorem ipsum dolor silit
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```